# On using a string with the roman character 'I' its giving 8 instead of 1. similarly 24 instead of 3 for 'III'

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

The rest of the part which includes string like 'IV' are yet to be done, but right now the problem is for 'I' the program is returning 8 instead of 1;

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> //header file
using namespace std;
  
int romantoint(char str[],int &n)
{
    int total=0;
    unordered_map <char,int> m;
    m['I'] = 1;
    m['II'] = 2;
    m['III'] = 3;
    m['IV'] = 4;
    m['V'] = 5;
    m['VI'] = 6;
    m['VII'] = 7;
    m['VIII'] = 8;
    m['IX'] = 9;
    m['X'] = 10;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      total = total+m[str[i]];
    }

    return total;
    
}




int main()
{
  char str[] = "I";
  int n = strlen(str);
  cout<<romantoint(str,n);
}
```

Comment: Use `std::string` as key, a single `char` doesn't work for that.

Comment: I get several "warning: multi-character character constant" if I try to compile that. Enable more warnings and don't ignore them.

Comment: Please read [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `m['I']` is fine. If you only had that it would work. `m['VIII']` isn't.

Comment: Understand the difference between a char and a string. `'I'` is a char, `"I"` is a string, but `'II'` is a multibyte char, something that is non-standard.

Comment: @MikeVine thanks it did!!. but why though is there a problem of duplicate characters in here?

Comment: What's happening in practice is that `'VIII'` is truncated to `'I'`.

Comment: There's no indication here that you are using the right *algorithm* to convert Roman to Decimal. This is coding by wishful thinking (which never works).

Comment: @john got it thanks was doing that only in the first place but idk why it showed an error in the m[str[i]];

Comment: @Akshatkant What error did you get with `m[str[i]]`? That looks OK to me.

Comment: i did this and got this error (no operator "[]" matches these operands)

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int romantoint(string &str,int &n)
{
    int total;
    map <string,int> m;
    m["I"] = 1;
    m["II"] = 2;
    m["III"] = 3;
    m["IV"] = 4;
    m["V"] = 5;
    m["VI"] = 6;
    m["VII"] = 7;
    m["VIII"] = 8;
    m["IX"] = 9;
    m["X"] = 10;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      total = total+ m[str[i]];
    }

    return total;
    
}




int main()
{
  string str = "XVII";
  int n = str.size();
  cout<<romantoint(str,n);
} @john

Comment: @Akshatkant Of course because those are strings not chars. You need to decide whether you want chars or strings in your map, but you cannot have multichar charcaters like '`III'`, that will not work. So either **single** characters, or strings (which can have multiple characters).

Answer (score 5):

```
 unordered_map <char,int> m;
```

This line tells the compiler that you are going to be mapping *a character to an integer*. Whereas when you've initialized the map, you've instead mapped the *string value of 'VIII'* to 8. Since the key HAS to be a character, you're actually *overwriting* the `m['I']= 1` map when you're mapping `m['VIII']=8` . This is the reason you're getting 8 when you try to find the value mapped to `m['I']` since the key is NOT supposed to be anything more than a single character.

P.S this looks like a function from which you want to return the corresponding integer value taking in it's roman numeral equivalent.
I would suggest using the same  `unordered_map <char,int> m;`map, but instead of directly mapping VIII to 8, rather use the maps from *V (=5)* and *I (=1)* to figure out the value of VIII using program logic ;)